# Верно ли расставлены знаки пунктуации в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение:
"За доступом к компьютеру от имени администратора, обращаться на электронную почту".

Смысл предложения: чтобы получить права администратора в компьютере, нужно кому-то написать на электронную почту.

Comment: ...пунктуации в предл.? ======= лучше так — пунк. в предл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За доступом к компьютеру от имени администратора обращаться на электронную почту.

Это простое предложение (односоставное, безличное инфинитивное), сочетание "за доступом к компьютеру от имени администратора" не обособляется.

Comment: А не будет ли в Вашем варианте похоже на то, будто Вы просите обратиться в письме от лица администратора?

Comment: Будет похоже, но только тут дело не в запятой, а в  неясных формулировках самого предложения. Можно предложить такой вариант:  "Для доступа к компьютеру на правах администратора следует обращаться на электронную почту".  Хорошо бы еще указать адрес этой почты или как-то еще ее определить.